# creating list from array with backbone and underscore

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, background, underscore.js

I have stored some data on local storage. I read data on localstorage with

```
 localStorage.getItem('students');
```

The read from local storage results

```
 [
  {
    "studentName":"John",
    "rollno":"12",
    "address1":"add1",
    "address2":"add2",
    "city":"Jackson Height",
     "state":"New York",
    "zip":"0111"
  },
 {
   "studentName":"Mohan",
    "rollno":"13",
    "address1":"add3",
    "address2":"add5",
    "city":"Mackson Height",
    "state":"New york",
    "zip":"004"
}
]
```

I am using backbone and underscore. I want to generate html as follows with underscore template from above student json data from local storage and hook it to some

```
 <ul>
      <li ><strong>Appointments</strong></li>
      //I want to create list from here from student data from localstorage
      <li>student name 1 rollno</li>
      <li>student name 2</li>

 </ul>
```

How can I do this?  Also, i wanted each list to be some model or something so that when i click on it, it allows me to go some view that will display all fields in students.Do in need to create model or collection though i take data from local-storage?

Comment: Seriously? Have you even tried?

Comment: @LiorCohen, I am new to backbone and underscore both. I have tried it and geting no idea. I got confused even i need to create model and collection or not while i read from data from localstorage itself too.

Comment: While that's fine and good, this isn't a "write my code" kinda place. Show us what you've tried and if you have no idea what you're doing, spend some quality time learning. Would you drive a car by sticking your head out the window asking people for instructions or would you actually take a few driving lessons first?

Comment: Lior Cohen's right, I just show a direction

Answer (score 1):

eh... this is a little complicated if you want make every "li" as a view. This is my solution:

You need a super-view to hold the ul, and create sub-views as many as you want in this super-view.

```
// this is the sub view, it's stand for every student
var SubView = Backbone.View.extend({

    // every student's name display in a li
    template: _.template('<li><%= obj.studentName %></li>'),

    // let every sub view react click event
    events: {
        'click': 'showDetail'
    },

    // draw li
    render: function() {
        // model will be passed in went sub view was created, and sub view append to ul
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON())).appendTo('.ul');
    },

    showDetail: function() {
        // here is your function to show student's detail
        // note you got the student data when this view was create
        // so you can refer it with this.model
    }

});

// this is the super view 
var SuperView = Backbone.View.extend({

    // catch ul, i assume it is the only one ul exists on your page
    el: $('ul'),

    // run on super view was createc
    initialize: function() {

        // get your students
        var students = localStorage.getItem('students');

        // loop through students
        _.each(students, function(student) {

            // create sub view(li) for every student
            var subView = new SubView({
                // a little tricky here, wrap your student data into model
                // and pass it (or say save it) in every sub view
                model: new Backbone.Model.extend(student);
            });

            // render the sub view
            subView.render();
        });
    }

});
```

after all this, just do "new SuperView()". and should be what you want.

this code is just an idea, I didn't run it actually.

Comment: thanks, it has been great direction for backbone,js beginner like me.